# Plotting library for Windows Phone 7 / Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any plotting control/library for Windows Phone 7 / Silverlight? I want to plot a signal, ideally with the ability to pinch zoom it and pan it (but thats too much to expect probably :)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a free one, and if you're only plotting one set of data, it's great.  Pinch-Zoom on the horizontal axis.

http://touchgraphwp7.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with the tools here: http://www.visifire.com/

They have a 30 day trial, but you have to buy the full version if you want to actually use it for your apps.  It is pretty nice, and it supports zooming and scrolling.  I didn't end up using it very much in the app I was making though, so I don't really know how comprehensive or useful it will end up being.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Quick Charts by amCharts. It's a set of free controls that might be able to do the job. Check out their website [here](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick)